# async => TRUE in drupal_add_js() : asynchronous call for a js file

Tags: php, asynchronous, drupal, drupal-7

I'm not an expert Drupal and PHP..
I would like to add a js file asynchronous but i don't know how. Now when I add a js file to my Drupal website (7.x) i use

```
drupal_add_js(path_to_theme() . '/scripts/Home.js');
```

but now i would like to add a js file asynchronous. Maybe i should to add

```
 async => TRUE
```

but i don't know where....

So please can you help me and show how rewrite `drupal_add_js` ?

I hope you can help me, thanks a lot and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do that with the "Asynchronous JavaScript" module for Drupal 7 at : https://www.drupal.org/project/async_js

Or you could implement **hook_js_alter()** and add in the async = TRUE key to the external file. Check this link on Drupal: https://www.drupal.org/node/2299773

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add an external javascript to your head you can use [drupal_add_html_head](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_html_head/7.x) like this

```php
  $element = [
    '#tag' => 'script',
    '#value' => '',
    '#attributes' => [
      'src' => 'https://www.example.com/example.js',
      'type' => 'application/javascript',
      'async' => "async",
    ],
  ];
  drupal_add_html_head($element, 'my_async_js');
```